# Pyspark double character replacement in strings avoiding certain words without mapping to pandas or rdd

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have inherited a program which modifies some strings in a pyspark dataframe. One of the steps involves removing double/triple/etc letters from some words in the strings, with an additional list of exceptions that are left alone even if they have repeated letters. Currently this is done by converting the dataframe to pandas with a udf, then applying a custom function to the strings in the resulting pandas dataframe, before reading back to pyspark. Unfortunately, changes to the requirements mean the code cannot under any circumstances use a pandas udf or be mapped to an rdd. I need to perform the same function directly in pyspark.

The consecutive char removing function reads in the strings word by word, checks if the word is in the exceptions list, if its not, moves character by character, comparing it to the previous character, if there is a match, checks if the creates a new word, character by character, omitting repeats.

Below is a MWE of the current implementation, after the pyspark dataframe is converted to pandas.

```
import pandas as pd


exception_list = ['ACCOUNTING', 'LOOK', 'FOOOOO']

cols = ['input']
data = [
    ["BOOK TOOK LOOK HOUSE SHOOK"],
    ["ACCOUNTING SHEEP"],
    ["FOO FOOO FOOOO FOOOOO FOOOOOO"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df.head()


def drop_consecutive_chars(phrase, exception):
    if phrase == '':
        return phrase
    else:
        new_phrase = []
        for word in phrase.split():
            if word not in exception:
                prev = word[0]
                new_word = prev
                for char in word[1:]:
                    if char != prev:
                        new_word += char
                    prev = char
            else:
                new_word = word
            new_phrase += [new_word]
        new_phrase = ' '.join(new_phrase)
        return new_phrase


df['output'] = df['input'].apply(drop_consecutive_chars,
                                 exception=exception_list)

df.head()
```

Any way to do this in pyspark? I am open to using things like RegexTokenizer and joining it back later, as well as creating additional truth columns which are dropped after. It just needs to be done without the dataframe ever leaving pyspark, or being mapped to anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my previous answer, you can use higher order functions to represent the logic of your Python code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = sdf.withColumn(
    'exception_list', 
    F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in exception_list])
).withColumn(
    'output', 
    F.expr("""
        concat_ws(' ', 
            transform(
                split(input, ' '), 
                w -> case when array_contains(exception_list, w) 
                     then w 
                     else concat_ws('', 
                         transform(
                             split(w, ''), 
                             (c, i) -> case when i = 0 or c != split(w, '')[i-1]
                                            then c
                                            else ''
                                            end
                         )
                     )
                     end
            )
       )
    """)
).drop('exception_list')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
|input                        |output                 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
|BOOK TOOK LOOK HOUSE SHOOK   |BOK TOK LOOK HOUSE SHOK|
|ACCOUNTING SHEEP             |ACCOUNTING SHEP        |
|FOO FOOO FOOOO FOOOOO FOOOOOO|FO FO FO FOOOOO FO     |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: I had a feeling the answer would be similar. Unfortunately, expression code (I am assuming this is Scala?) is unknown to me. I tried for a while to get something like this to work, but was going about it the wrong way. Thank you again. Will test now.

Comment: That's not Scala - it's SQL. But the functional programming approach (transform/filter/aggregate) is very Scala-like

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an error with this: AnalysisException: "The number of lambda function arguments '2' does not match the number of arguments expected by the higher order function '1'. Its pointing to somewhere inside the expression, potentially at the w -> array_contains line, but I cant be sure.

Comment: What's your spark version? 2.4?

Comment: I changed the code to be comptaible with spark 2.4.

Comment: We are unfortunately not able to give out that information (which makes this really hard!)